# How to close browser window, then reopen, but keep previous session cookies?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to check if my "Keep me signed in" checkbox working properly.
So I create a new driver instance, open the login page etc...

However to check if "Keep me signed in" is working properly now I have to close the browser window, and reopen it. The trap is that this case it is opened from the "virgin" profile, so regardless what the previous instance did, the state will be the same stater state.

**Question**

Is there any way to close the browser window, and reopen it where in the previous session closed?

Answer (score 2):

Using Python:
Lets use `https://stackoverflow.com/` as an example.  The scrip below will navigate to this website and give you time to login. Then it will close and open again and load the cookies from the pervious session so you are logged in. You may not need a whole minuet to login, just adjust that sleep to what you are looking for. The `driver.close()` at the end is commented out so you can click around and make sure you are logged in as you expect.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pickle
import os

service = Service('C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
    
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
time.sleep(60)
# #########################
#
# #LOGIN TO STACKOVERFLOW
#
# ########################
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("C:/Py/cookie/cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.close()


time.sleep(2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
cookies = pickle.load(open("C:/Py/cookie/cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
time.sleep(2)
# driver.close()
```

Comment: IMO, during the second iteration you need to login as well then load the cookies, else the cookies may complain of being _from different domains_

Comment: Good catch, I updated the answer to handle that scenario.  It will now check to see if the cookies file exists and if it already exists it will just use the existing file.

Comment: @DebanjanB the exception about different domain has nothing to do with the *login*. It caused by the lack of the *navigation*. Before adding the cookies, the browser must navigate to the very same domain as the cookies were originally added.

Comment: @Jortega, many thx, I am still working on a usable version, but you enlighted the way. Please read my prev. comment, and undo the edit.

Comment: The edit is now reverted.